# Python: how to iterate through and rename shape keys?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, shape-keys

I have a model with Japanese characters in the names of objects throughout the model. I've found this script which translates those names into english:

https://github.com/toruta39/blender-datablock-translator

It works well, however, it does not translate the names of shape keys. I'm attempting to modify the script to include shape keys but have not been successful. I believe shape keys data are stored in bpy.data.shape_keys. How do I loop through shape keys and modify each name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about this?

```
import bpy

for shapekey in bpy.data.shape_keys:
    # rename / translate shape key names by changing shapekey.name
    for keyblock in shapekey.key_blocks:
        # rename / translate block key names by changing keyblock.name
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks! I knew it had to be simple, but I'm new to Python.

Comment: Note, even though you can use `bpy.data.shape_keys`, typically these are accessed via the mesh.